# How do you create an install wizard like the Visual Studio 2013 Style?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, setup-project

Can anyone tell me how I can create an install package so that when the user installs it he/she is presented with a Install Wizard like the one used to install Visual Studio 2013. 
I'm talking about the modern UI look and feel i.e the dark gray screen with the Blue buttons that say install or skip etc...

Is there like a Visual Studio Extension or template I need to download?

I've googled everywhere without any success.

JetBrains Rehsharper seem to have this, image below:

https://ericnelson.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/capture.jpg

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There are third-party tools that might help you achieve your goal. I haven't used many of them, but I think [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/index.html) would be a good choice. It offers Visual Studio integration and has a "theme" named *Surface* that seems to be what you're looking for. Check out the [screenshots section on their website](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/screen-shots.html).

[Surface theme screenshot](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/surface-screen-shot.html).

Answer (score 0):

The VS 2013 Community Edition install was built with WiX - I'm pretty sure the other editions were too. Search for custom bootstrapper applications like these:

http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/

https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/